# Make Spark run faster when run locally, for training purposes

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My team builds and maintains an API built on top of PySpark SQL. It is meant for production use cases, and does a good job at scaling to large data on clusters. We can also run it locally, which is useful for development, testing, and training people via interactive exercise sessions using Jupyter notebooks.

However, running fairly simple computations on Spark takes a little while, frequently a few dozens seconds, even on a dataframe of about 50k rows. Our library is to do differential privacy, which involves some randomization. Thus, training use cases involve running the same analysis multiple times to get average utility metrics. This means that runtimes quickly reach a few minutes, which is annoyingly long when you're trying to run a 1-2h exercise session.

My question is: are there Spark configuration options I could tweak to lower this runtime for small-data, single-machine use cases, and make teaching a little smoother?